# Save PDF then send in email

Tags: iphone, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to save a pdf from a url and then send it in an email. The sender seems to have it but the receiver does not get it.

When I do a `NSLog` of the `NSString file` I get `/var/mobile/Applications/0ADE222E-6346-4C6C-8348-DA5327B980AA/Documents/myPDF.pdf`

It seems like it saves but it doesn't send. Here is my code below for saving and sending

**EDIT**

**Updated code**

```
    // This pdfURL is 0 bytes
    NSData *pdfURL = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",webPage.urlString]]];

    //Store the Data locally as PDF File
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *file = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/myPDF.pdf"];

    [pdfURL writeToFile:file atomically:YES];

    //Sending the pdf
    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;        
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
        //Changed email for privacy issues
        [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"123@abc.com", nil]];
        [composer setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ email",titleText]];
        [composer setMessageBody:@"your custom body content" isHTML:NO];

        NSLog(@"pdf %@",file);
        // This pdfData is 0 bytes
        NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];

        [composer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"myPDF.pdf"];

        [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
        [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];            
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried without the "/" in the filename portion of your addAttachmentData call?

Comment: Yes I have. I have it there because of previous things I have read. It does not work either way though

Comment: Just before your call to addAttachmentData, can you check the size of your pdfData to make sure there is something truly being read?

Comment: Ya you are right. The pdfData is 0 bytes. Does that mean the file is empty or the NSData is not getting the pdf contents?

Comment: Yeah, that probably means the file is not there. Try using the SAME EXACT code for generating the path that you used when saving the image (just to make 100% SURE they are truly matching paths).

Comment: I used filePath instead of creating a new one and still the pdfData is 0 bytes. So my guess is that I am not saving it properly .

Comment: Not necessarily, are you testing on the actual device, or are you testing on the simulator?  I actually HAVE had this exact thing happen before where I saved a file off, and if I tried to reference it back in to quickly, it wasnt there.  If I closed my app, then re-opened it, the file was magically there!!!  Solved the functional problem by continuously holding a copy in RAM for internal use, and only referencing the copy on disk when initializing!!!  Weird, but true...  Try writing a snipit that allows you to see if the file is there when you just open your app!!!

Comment: Just for one more check also, check the size of your pdfData variable prior to saving also!!! Make sure it isnt somehow 0 bytes there also!!!  Just out of curiosity, why are you needing to save it, if the point is simply to send it?

Comment: I am testing on an actual device. The simulator can send messages I dont think. I have restarted my phone and still the file isn't there. When I check before the `pdfData` is created it is just `bytes` but after when I run the line `NSData pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOFile:file]` `pdfData` is `0 bytes`

Comment: DO an NSLog of filePath just prior to your call to the writeToFile method!

Comment: If you check the updated code the pdfURL is empty so that is the issue.

Comment: So where are you getting "webPage.urlString"?  The updated code would not have been able to show me that the URL string was empty :-)

Comment: Ya I realized that after :P. The issue was the webPage.urlString was not being properly passed. Thanks for your help. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Hi guys, when the email composer shows up, it becomes very SLOW because it's previewing the PDF in the body of the composer. Is there any way to disabled the preview to not have a SLOW DOWN? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the webPage.urlString being empty. This code works just make sure the url string is not empty :P

Answer (score 1):

If it's from a URL, store it in NSData:

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL Of Pdf"]];
```

And then attach that to mail